# Django specify manually fields to include as nested JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

With django-rest-framework I'm creating a REST API where I can access and modify information about people in a city. People belong to a city, and therefore have a foreign key linking to the City model.

With the code below, I'm serializing the Person object along with the City object resulting in nested JSON. However, as this is a simplified code example, and the real project has much more data and fields, and the nesting goes deeper, it ends up slowing down the API greatly, especially when accessing all Person entries.

Is there a way to optionally specify if I want to include the nested serialization, or if I just want the shallow Person model with the primary key ids?

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=384)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = '__all__'


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

**urls.py:**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('people', PersonViewSet)
```

**requesting data:**
    curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" 'localhost:8000/people'

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Simen",
        "city": {
            id: 1,
            name: "Oslo"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Roar",
        "city": {
            id: 2,
            name: "Trondheim"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: add `depth=1` (or any other suitable number for your use case) in serializer meta

Answer (score 0):

You could make two separate serializers. You’d call one when you want to use a nested object, the other when you don’t. When you don’t want a nested object, make the city field of the new person person serializer be the id of city.

Comment: How would you decide which one to return to the user? I updated my question with a `ViewSet` for `Person`

Comment: When are you trying to send a flat response and when are you trying to send a nested response?

Comment: I was asking in general, since I don't know how to do it yet on the back end I'm not doing it at all. I've updated the question with a curl request. I'm building an API so the functionality is useful for users in different situations.

Comment: Your question implies that there are times you would like a flat response and there are times you would a nested response. I was just trying to pry out that logic from you. Generally this behavior is handled in your view. If this is the case let me know and I can provide an example